# Finding a image link and clicking with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm automating some things on a website. I need to check if a "Next" button is there on a page and then click on it. This is the HTML.

```
<a  href="javascript:goToPage(2);"><span class="txt_purple"></span><img align="absmiddle" src="/icon_next.jpg"  border="0" /></a>
```

I can use getElementsByTagName('img') to find the image and then how do I do the click?

**UPDATED WITH ANSWER:**

Adding an id isn't possible in this case. I don't have control over the webpages. It is somebody else's site so I have to do with what's already there. This is what I did:

```
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].hasAttribute('src') && e[i].getAttribute('src') == '/icon_next.jpg') {
      e[i].click();
      break;
    }
```

Comment: <a> is not guaranteed to have click handler, see my updated answer.

Comment: Probably better to just define the onclick directly as per my second update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I need to check if a "Next" button is there on a page"

If you want to find out if an element exists:

```
if(document.getElementById("someID")){
```

---

> "and then click on it"

**Edit 1**

See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEJLW/1/)** - the click event is raised on page load. You can also click directly on the `<a>`

There is a bit more to this than you might think, because you are trying to invoke click of an `<a>`. These are not guaranteed to have a click event handler. See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20942402/746754)**.  You need something like:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myNext');
if( elem )
{
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initEvent("click", true, false);
    elem.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

However, it is a bit of a hack. You probably just want to define the onclick directly on the `a` and call the function.

**Edit 2**

What you probably really want is to define the onclick on the a href itself. See this **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xEJLW/3/)**. The function is fired on page load as well as if you click the `a` passing in the element in each case.

HTML:

```
<a  id="myNext" href="#" onclick="clickAction(this)">
    <span class="txt_purple"></span>
    <img align="absmiddle" src="<yoursource>"  border="0"/>
</a>
```

Then call the function appropriately:

```
function clickAction(element)
{
    alert(element);
}

var elem = document.getElementById('myNext');
if( elem )
{
    clickAction(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Add an id to your image `id=next`

```
<a  href="javascript:goToPage(2);">
    <span class="txt_purple"></span>
    <img id="next" align="absmiddle" src="/icon_next.jpg"  border="0" />
</a>
```

Then use

```
document.getElementById("next").click()
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I'm not looking for an onClick handler. I'm looking to trigger a click.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can find the image, you can automate a click by using:

```
document.getElementById('iwanttoclickthis').click();
```